# Size of templated polymorphic derived classes without new members

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, sizeof, placement-new

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    virtual T* get() const = 0;
protected:
    void *c_;
};

template <typename C, typename T>
struct WrapperOf: Wrapper<T> {

    WrapperOf(C *c = 0) : c_(c) { }

    virtual T* get() const {
        C *c = static_cast<C*>(c_);
        return static_cast<T*>(c->get());
    }
};
```

Is it guaranteed by the standard that the size of any `WrapperOf` will be the same? Typically, could I do the following:

```
struct Dummy { void* get(); };
struct Real { int* get(); };

char storage[sizeof(WrapperOf<Dummy, void>)];
Wrapper<int> *wp = 
    new(storage) WrapperOf<Real, int>();
```

And if I specialize `WrapperOf`, typically:

```
template <>
struct WrapperOf<void, void>: Wrapper<void> {
    virtual void* get() const { return 0; }
};
```

To use it to initialize the storage (to avoid having a `Dummy` class):

```
char storage[sizeof(WrapperOf<void, void>)];
```

Would this still be valid?

Comment: So your asking if `sizeof(WrapperOf<A, B>) == sizeof(WrapperOf<X, Y>)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver and same alignment as a `char[]`...

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, exactly - Or at least if `sizeof(WrapperOf<A, X>) == sizeof(WrapperOf<B, X>)`.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something... since the only data member is `void *c_`, shouldn't `sizeof(Wrapper<T>) == sizeof(void*) + sizeof([vtable])`, where `[vtable]` is however the compiler handles the vtable?  Because if so, we can establish that `WrapperOf<T, U>` should always have the same size, regardless of template parameters, because it will always have the same two members: a `void*` data member, and the vtable pointer.

Comment: Testing with [Clang, GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/960062075d4f0f6d), and [MSVC](http://rextester.com/GKV30201) suggests this is the case.  [I also told MSVC to output class layouts.  All instantiations of `Wrapper` have members `{vfptr}` and `c_`, and all instantiations of `WrapperOf` have a base `Wrapper` and no other members.  Note that MSVC implements vtables differently than the others, but all three appear to store a pointer to the vtable in the class itself.]

Comment: So, for any given C++ compiler, all instantiations of `Wrapper` and `WrapperOf` should have the same size; this size isn't guaranteed to be the same across all compilers, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the current working draft [N4640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4640.pdf) (2017-02-06)

> **5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]**
>
> 1. The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand.
> 2. ... When applied
>    to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in an array.

So there's no guaranty about anything, just that it takes so much bytes as it takes.

Even for most fundamental types, the standard says it is *implementation-defined*

> 1. ... sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined.

One can infer that it takes N bytes for some class and empirically see that it is the same for a range of derived classes in a given implementation. There is just no guaranty.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not guaranteed in standard anywhere, since standard doesn't really make any guarantees about object sizes, except for some narrow cases.

It also worth noting that Standard doesn't say anything about virtual functions implementations (things like vptr do not exist in standard).

Answer (score 1):

The only types that have guarantees about size are standard layout types. Being polymorphic (amongst others) specifically precludes this.

However, you can do what you want (I am assuming you want to allocate sufficient space to create any kind of a set of WrapperOf's):

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

struct Dummy { void* get(); };
struct Real { int* get(); };
struct UnReal { float* get(); };

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(void* c) : c_(c) {}
    virtual T* get() const = 0;
    void* get_c() { return c_; }
    void* get_c() const { return c_; }
protected:
    void *c_;
};


template <typename C, typename T>
struct WrapperOf: Wrapper<T> {

    WrapperOf(C *c = 0) : Wrapper<T>(c) { }

    virtual T* get() const {
        C *c = static_cast<C*>(this->get_c());
        return static_cast<T*>(c->get());
    }
};

template <>
struct WrapperOf<void, void>: Wrapper<void> {
    virtual void* get() const { return 0; }
};

template<class Type, class...Rest>
struct largest_of
{
    static constexpr auto x = sizeof(Type);
    static constexpr auto y = largest_of<Rest...>::size;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = x > y ? x : y;

    static constexpr auto q = alignof(Type);
    static constexpr auto p = largest_of<Rest...>::alignment;
    static constexpr std::size_t alignment = q > p ? q : p;
};

template<class T> struct largest_of<T>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T); 
    static constexpr std::size_t alignment = alignof(T);
};

template<class...Ts> struct largest_of<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = largest_of<Ts...>::size; 
    static constexpr std::size_t alignment =largest_of<Ts...>::alignment;
};

using candidates = std::tuple<
    WrapperOf<Real, int>,
    WrapperOf<UnReal, float>,
    WrapperOf<Dummy, void>,
    WrapperOf<void, void>
>;

using largest = largest_of<candidates>;
std::aligned_storage<largest::size, largest::alignment> storage;

int main()
{
    auto p1 = new (std::addressof(storage)) WrapperOf<Real,int>();
    p1->~WrapperOf<Real,int>();

    auto p2 = new (std::addressof(storage)) WrapperOf<UnReal, float>();
    p2->~WrapperOf<UnReal,float>();
}
```